# Managed property not showing in Display template

Tags: search, bcs, display-template, crawling, managed-property

We have a BCS-model which gets data from a database outside of SharePoint.
We make data from the BCS searchable by creating managed properties and then mapping them to the auto generated crawled properties from the BCS model.

I am developing a custom display template where I want to show that data from BCS. I can show some of the managed properties by accessing "ctx.CurrentItem", but not all of them.  I.e I have a managed property called "CaseDate" which is not available on "ctx.CurrentItem". I can retrieve "CaseDate" by using rest API, but cannot find a way to access/show it in my display template.

Is there a way I can get a spesific managed property in my display template? How can I get the "CaseDate" in my display template ?

Edit: There is no error in crawl, and I have also tried "CaseDate" as managed property in ManagedProertyMapping in the display template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was editing standard search results web part. The reason why my mapped properties where not showing was because I only added the mapped property in the display template that shows the hover panel (Item_Commonhoverpanel_Body). I had to add the managed properties in the Item_Default also, or else it would not show them in the hover panel.

Of course I created my own display templates, and did not destroy the ones that ship with SharePoint.

This link helped me a lot:

> When adding custom properties to a hover panel, you have to add them
>   to the item display template

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/09/12/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-the-hover-panel-in-sharepoint-server-2013/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have included that managed property in the listing at the top of the item template?
What does the Sharepoint search query tool show?

Comment: Yes. I am 100% sure of that. The Search Query tool show the value of "CaseDate" and all other fields I can not see value of.

Answer (score 0):

After you created the Result Type Rule for your Display Template, did you go back to the Result Type Rule page? Sometimes there will be a yellow message saying your properties need to be updated. Click the affirmative action (the message should turn green) and try again.

Comment: I did not create any result type rule for the display template. Is that required ?

Comment: No, not required, but may help identifying the issue. You can delete it later. How are you showing your DT? Are you forcing it in the Results web part?

Comment: I was using result type without knowing it. I edited the standard search results web part. I found out that I had to map the properties in Item_Defaul.html, and not just in the hover panel as I was doint.

Comment: Right, if you want them in the HP you need them in the calling Display Template as well. Got it working?